# JSON invalid syntax between js and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have this code:

```
   var temp = 'tag1,tag2'.split(','),
       tags = [];

     if (temp.length > 0) {
         for (i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i) {
             tags.push(temp[i]);
         }
     }
```

Now I want to send this array as an Ajax request:

```
        var data = {
            action: 'my_wp_ajax',
            ajax_req: JSON.stringify(tags)
        };

        $.post(
            ajaxurl,
            data,
            function (data) {

                console.log('this is data: '+data);

            }
        );
```

On the other side I have these codes:

```
echo $_POST['ajax_req'];

$temp = json_decode($_POST['ajax_req']);
$error = json_last_error();

echo $error;
```

The result I see in browser console is:

```
this is data: "[\\\"tag1\\\",\\\"tag2\\\"]4"
```

As you can see in above result, last json error is 4 which means invalid json syntax. I don't know what is wrong in above codes. If I try

```
foreach (json_decode($_POST['ajax_req']) as $hi)
    echo $hi;
```

In console it only shows me

```
this is data: ""
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I tried `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc(), $_POST);` and the result in console:

```
"bool(false)\narray(2) {\n  [\"action\"]=>\n  string(8) \"my_wp_ajax\"\n  [\"ajax_req\"]=>\n  string(19) \"[\\\"tag1\\\",\\\"tag2\\\"]\"\n}\n0"
```

Comment: Check the request in the console - is the `4` added when the data is sent?

Comment: You're double encoding parts of the data. Skip the first stringify. Jquery will do it for you.

Comment: I cannot replicate this, copying and pasting the above into relevant local files. I get `this is data: ["tag1","tag2"]0` as I would expect. I can't immediately think of a PHP config setting that woudl be relevant (but I'm not a PHP expert, either).

Comment: @Yoshi: No, he/she isn't. They're posting JSON in a URI-encoded form submission. Perfectly valid way to send JSON to the server. Not the *only* way, but a perfectly valid way.

Comment: Side note: Why can't you use `temp` directly? Why create a second array and then copy the contents to it? `temp` is *already* an array. Just `var tags = 'tag1,tag2'.split(',');`

Comment: Can you do edit your php file so it reads `<?php var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc(), $_POST);` and then post the output after sending the ajax request?
Also, if that returns error 500, can you post output of `<?php var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: As @Yoshi mentioned, it encoded twice. I deleted `JSON.stringify` and it works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I simplified the codes because of that `temp` looks unnecessary.

Comment: @ata: Again: It **isn't** encoded twice, in the code above. If you eliminated the `JSON.stringify`, you're no longer sending JSON to the server. If you don't want to send JSON to the server, get rid of *both* `JSON.stringify` and `json_decode`. If you *do*, you need to keep both.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm confused, what was the problem then? Now I can receive array in php.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what is your PHP version?

Comment: @ata: My PHP version is irrelevant (but it's 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22), none of this has changed in years. Your `json_decode` without `JSON.stringify` is working because `$_POST['ajax_req']` returns an **array**, which is then being converted to string (because `json_decode` expects a string), which just happens to be something that `json_decode` will then parse back into an array. It's not *correct*, though. If you don't want to send JSON, just use `$_POST['ajax_req']` directly (without using `JSON.stringify` on the client).

Comment: @ata: Do you want to send JSON or not? Is what you're sending just a simple array of strings?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want json. These codes are simplified. What I wanna do is complicated than simple array.

Comment: ata - *(FWIW: "Want to", not "wanna".)* Okay. Then you need to do what you were doing (ignore the incorrect posted answer). Please update the question with the **exact content** of a minimal HTML/JS page that replicates the problem and the **exact content** of a minimal PHP page it calls, along with the answer to the question @Damir asked. Again: With what's in the question, the problem doesn't occur barring some weird config thing which I very much doubt is the issue. I suspect the problem is in something you've removed for the question without realizing it's relevant. We'll get there! :-)

Comment: (Well, okay, it's encoded twice -- once as JSON and once as a URI-encoded form field -- but that's fine and if you have other URI-encoded fields you're sending [which you do in the question], it's perfectly appropriate.)

Comment: We'll get there...if you don't disappear, and if you post the requested information.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm here! I should post all the codes? there are many irrelevant codes in there.I'm sure there is nothing else related to this problem. If you think this is necessary, please tell me and I'll all the codes.

Comment: @ata: No, you should post a [mcve], emphasis on the "minimal." Strip away all the irrelevancies. (That article is well worth reading.) For instance, my HTML/JS is [like this](https://pastebin.com/UbnzHxzj) (what you have, but I've added a declaration for `i`), and my PHP is [like this](https://pastebin.com/PwJTL10L), and I can't replicate the problem you describe. So your goal is to create **complete** examples (like this) but that demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need to double stringify array, `data` passed to array is going to be properly handled by jQuery:

```
var tags = 'tag1,tag2'.split(',');
var data = {
    action: 'my_wp_ajax',
    ajax_req: tags
};
```

Comment: It's not being double-stringified in the code shown. It's being stringified, and then put in a URI-encoded form submission. Perfectly valid way to send JSON to the server. (Not the only way, but a perfectly valid way.)

Comment: Opposite comment is upvoted but this reply solved my problem. How is that? jQuery encode data automatically?

Comment: @ata Yes, if you pass array like you are passing it will be JSON.stringified by jQuery for you.

Comment: Do you know a resource to suggest? I want to know more about it.

Comment: @dfsq: **No**, it will not. It will send repeated `ajax_req[]` fields, which PHP interprets as an array. No JSON. (No `json_decode` required or appropriate.) Just look at the Network tab to see what's being sent. What makes you think it will? Citation please.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, of course, I wrote JSON.stringified. I meant "encoded". In this cases it will be like if there were multiple `<input name="ajax_req[]">`

Comment: @dfsq: Right. The OP has confirmed that they need to send JSON in that field, though; the quoted code is just a simplified example.